# ¿Cómo guardar varios resultados de Random Forest en una lista o vector?

Tags: r, bucle-for

Estoy evaluando modelos de Random Forest en R. Estos modelos son iguales, con la excepción de un parámetro que cambio consecutivamente. Un extracto del código que empleo es el siguiente:

```
IMP30 = ImporFS1.30/(max(ImporFS1.30))
gamma = 0.1
coefReg30 = (1-gamma)+gamma*IMP30
FS4.30_0.1 = RRF(MEx30[,c(1:30)], as.factor(MEx30$Clasif),coefReg=coefReg30, flagReg=0)
```

El parámetro gamma cambia de 0.1 a 1, por lo cual podría poner este código en un ciclo for en lugar de generar las cuatro líneas anteriores 10 veces. Hice el intento de construir este ciclo de la siguiente forma:

```
Tab_EG_GRF = NULL
FS4.30 = NULL
sec = seq(0.1, 1, 0.1)
for(i in 1:length(sec)){
  gamma = sec[i]
  coefReg30 = (1-gamma)+gamma*IMP30 
  FS4.30[i] = RRF(MEx30[,c(1:30)], as.factor(MEx30$Clasif),coefReg=coefReg30, flagReg=0)
  EG = sum(diag(FS4.30$confusion))/sum(FS4.30$confusion[,c(1:6)])
  Tab_EG_GRF[i] = paste("FS4.30", sec[i], EG)
}
```

El problema que tengo es que en `FS4.30[i]` no se guarda el modelo completo de Random Forest. A continuación muestro una salida de este proceso:

```
> FS4.30[2]
[[1]]
RRF(x = MEx30[, c(1:30)], y = as.factor(MEx30$Clasif), coefReg = coefReg, 
    flagReg = 1)
```

Debería salir algo como esto:

```
> FS4.30_1

Call:
 RRF(x = MEx30[, c(1:30)], y = as.factor(MEx30$Clasif), coefReg = coefReg30,      flagReg = 0) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 5

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 17.18%
Confusion matrix:
    1    2   3   4  5   6 class.error
1 923  100  55  22  6  12  0.17441860
2  63 1023  12  13  2   4  0.08415398
3  84   23 232  66  0   1  0.42857143
4  10   12  46 945  0   0  0.06712734
5  78    4   2   2 28   1  0.75652174
6  41   10   4   7  3 142  0.31400966
```

Mi pregunta concreta es:

**¿Como hago para que se almacene cada uno de los resultados anteriores en una lista, vector o matriz?**

**¿Que otra forma existe para almacenar resultados complejos en listas, vectores o matrices?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estas buscando hacer, es generar variables dinámicamente para cada modelo, por supuesto se pude hacer, pero no es recomendable, ya que es más complejo el acceso automatizado a las mismas. Lo óptimo en estos casos, es crear una única lista dónde guardaremos cada modelo que hemos generado, a modo de ejemplo reproducible:

```
FS4.30 = list()
for(i in 1:5){
  FS4.30[[paste0("modelo.",i)]] <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars)
}
```

Básicamente:
+ Creamos una lista vacía `FS4.30`
+ Iteramos y vamos asignando los modelos generados a un nuevo ítem por nombre: `FS4.30[[paste0("modelo.",i)]]`, notar los `[[`.

Finalmente para acceder a cada modelo, podremos hacer mediante un índice numérico:

```
FS4.30[[1]]
FS4.30[[2]]
..
FS4.30[[5]]
```

O bien, mediante el nombre que hemos construido antes `paste0("modelo.",i)`, es decir:

```
FS4.30$modelo.1
FS4.30$modelo.2
..
FS4.30$modelo.5
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó muy bien